# Excel user defined function to return average of same range in all worksheets but this one

Tags: vba, excel

I could just do this with a formula if I knew how many worksheets there were. But I want to make a user defined function on the first worksheet that will loop from the second to the last worksheet no matter how many there are. No matter what I try, when I try to refer to another worksheet I get a #VALUE error. This, for example, doesn't work:

```
Function AVERANK(rng As Range) ' user passes the range in which people may have entered a rank for this benefit

Dim ws As Integer ' variable to hold worksheet index and increment through loop
Dim pageAve As Single ' variable to hold average value of the passed range for one worksheet, since people put their rank in different cells
' or put two ranks for one benefit
Dim ave As Single ' variable to hold the running total of rank
Dim cnt As Integer ' variable to hold count of worksheets for calculating average rank over all worksheets

cnt = 0 ' count starts as zero, incremented each time loop goes through a worksheet
ave = 0 ' average starts as zero, each worksheet's rank is added to it

For ws = 2 To ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count ' loop through all the worksheets but the first one
    pageAve = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets(ws).rng)
    ' sets pageAve to the average of the target range on this worksheet
    ave = ave + pageAve ' adds this worksheet's rank to the running total of rank
    cnt = cnt + 1 ' counts this worksheet
Next

AVERANK = ave / cnt ' calculates average rank of benefit over all worksheets


End Function
```

This seems to be working for me now:

```
Function WORKBOOKAVE(rng As Range) ' user passes the range in which people may have entered a rank for this benefit

Dim w As Long ' variable to hold worksheet index and increment through loop
Dim ave As Double ' variable to hold the running total of rank
Dim cnt As Long ' variable to hold count of worksheets for calculating average rank over all worksheets

For w = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count ' loop through all the worksheets
    With Worksheets(w)
        If .Name <> rng.Parent.Name Then ' excludes the worksheet in which the function was entered
            ave = ave + Application.Average(.Range(rng.Address)) ' adds this worksheet's rank to the running total of rank
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
            cnt = cnt + 1 ' counts this worksheet
        End If


    End With
Next

WORKBOOKAVE = ave / cnt ' calculates average rank of benefit over all worksheets

ErrHandler:
            ave = ave + 7 ' if they left this row blank, causing an error when calculating the average, assign the worst rank: 7
            Resume Next 'go back to the next line which counts this worksheet

End Function
```

Comment: What specifically would you want to occur if one of the worksheets being averaged had no values? This would normally throw a `#DIV/0!` error. Should the worksheet be discarded or should zeroes be added to a collective total to avoid the error? Or perhaps a third option I have not thought of...?

Comment: Since not assigning a rank seems to indicate they don't value it, for that worksheet it should get the worst rank, 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut down the code lines a bit.

```
Function AVERANK(rng As Range) ' user passes the range in which people may have entered a rank for this benefit

    Dim w As Long ' variable to hold worksheet index and increment through loop
    Dim ave As Double ' variable to hold the running total of rank
    Dim cnt As Long ' variable to hold count of worksheets for calculating average rank over all worksheets

    For w = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count ' loop through all the worksheets but the first one
        With Worksheets(w)
            'next line adjusted to include #DIV/0! error control as per Axel Richter's approach above
            If .Name <> rng.Parent.Name And CBool(Application.Count(.Range(rng.Address))) Then
                ' sets pageAve to the average of the target range on this worksheet
                ave = ave + Application.Average(.Range(rng.Address)) ' adds this worksheet's rank to the running total of rank
                cnt = cnt + 1 ' counts this worksheet
            End If
        End With
    Next

    AVERANK = ave / cnt ' calculates average rank of benefit over all worksheets

End Function
```

Declared numbers start their life out as zero; there is no need to assign them as **0** before use. The **rng** parameter passed in has the parent worksheet of the worksheet the function is in and that can be used to discard that worksheet from consideration.

Comment: You may wish to apply the [Application.Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx) method in order that changes in the worksheet will be accurately reflected in the UDF's results.

Comment: +1 for "all worksheets except the one the `rng` comes from" approach. And for the hint to `Application.Volatile`.

Comment: @JasmineVanPelt  - I've added #DIV/0! error control as per Axel Richter's approach. Also, remember that even with `Application.Volatile` added, the function is only recalculated when that worksheet is recalculated; not necessarily when other worksheets have their values changed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues.

`For ws = 2 To ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count` is not the right syntax for `For ... Next`.  `For ws = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count` would be.

`Worksheets(ws).rng` will not work. If you need the Range of the same address of given `rng` in the actual WS, then `Worksheets(ws).Range(rng.Address)` will work.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Average` will return a `Double` not a `Single`.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Average` will result in `#DIV/0` error if there are no values in the `Range`. So we should catch that error.

So the following should work:

```
Function AVERANK(rng As Range) As Double

 Dim ws As Integer
 Dim pageAve As Double
 Dim ave As Double
 Dim cnt As Integer
 Dim oActWS As Worksheet
 Dim oActRange As Range

 With ActiveWorkbook
  For ws = 2 To .Worksheets.Count ' right syntax For ... Next
   Set oActWS = .Worksheets(ws)
   Set oActRange = oActWS.Range(rng.Address) ' Range of the same address of given rng in the act. WS
   pageAve = 0 ' set pageAve=0 because if error, then it would remain the value from the worksheet before
   On Error Resume Next ' if there are no values, then there is a #DIV/0 error with Avarage
   pageAve = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(oActRange)
   On Error GoTo 0
   ave = ave + pageAve
   cnt = cnt + 1
  Next

 End With

 AVERANK = ave / cnt

End Function
```

Comment: Good catch on the *'no values gives a #DIV/0!'*. I has missed that salient point (might have used a COUNT function though).

Comment: Should `ave = ave + pageAve` be inside the #DIV/0! error control?

Comment: No, but we should set pageAve=0. Because if error, then it would remain the value from the worksheet before. So if no values, the avarage is 0.

Comment: Thanks for your educational answer! :)

Comment: As remarked above, pageAve should be set to 7, because 0 would mean better than 1, but if they leave it blank they probably don't think it's the most important of all. Not that I have any idea how to code that....

Comment: Not clear what you want. With my approach a worksheet with empty range will be counted with an avarage of 0 (`pageAve = 0`) or whatever `pageAve` you set in that code line. With Jeeped's approach a worksheet with empty range will not be counted at all, as if that worksheet would not be there. So you must choose what you want.